# How can I Fix this Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Using a Riemann Sum?

Tags: calculus

To prove the first Fundamental Theorem of Calculus I attempted to take the derivative of function *F(x)*, which is defined as:
$$
F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt
$$
I set up the difference quotient:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{a}^{x+\mathit{n}}(f(t)dt)-\int_{a}^{x}(f(t)dt)}{\mathit{n}}
$$
Subtracting out the area from *a* to *x* from the area of *a* to *x+n*, would leave you with the area from *x* to *x+n*. Causing the difference quotient to become:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{x}^{x+n}f(t)dt}{n}
$$
A function (f(x)) continuous at bounds [a, b] has an area below its curve at the given bounds defined as:
$$
\lim_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b-a}{g}\sum_{k=0}^{g-1}(f(a+\frac{b-a}{g}*k))
$$
Given the Riemann definition of an integral:
$$
\lim_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b-a}{g}\sum_{k=0}^{g-1}(f(a+\frac{b-a}{g}*k))=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
$$
Substituting:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{\lim_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{g}\sum_{k=0}^{g-1}f(x+\frac{nk}{g})}{n}
$$
Since n is a constant in the nested limit, it can be factored out and cancelled
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\lim_{g\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{g}\sum_{k=0}^{g-1}f(x+\frac{nk}{g})
$$
At this point I determined that if I could prove that the limits were commutative then I could compute them; however, they are not. Any hints or answers as to how to continue onwards, or corrections to my previous statements would help.

Comment: The point is that $f$ is continuous and all the terms are $f(x+z_k)$ where $0 \leq z_k \leq n$, so given $\varepsilon>0$ you have a $\delta>0$ such that all $g$ terms are within $\varepsilon$ of $f(x)$ as soon as $n<\delta$.

Comment: That  definition of an integral is not by the 19th-century Riemann.

Comment: The limit of all Riemann-sums is the definite integral of the function on the limits of integration.

Comment: How would you show ${\int_{a}^{x+\mathit{n}}(f(t)dt)-\int_{a}^{x}(f(t)dt)} = \int_{x}^{x+n}f(t)dt $ using this definition of the integral?

Answer (score 1):

For a continuous $f$ and for $a\le b$ let $f^+(x,a,b)=\max \{f(x): a\le x\le b\}$ and let $f^-(x,a,b)=\min \{f(x): a\le x\le b\}.$

Any finite sum as in your Q, that approximates $\int_a^bf(x)dx ,$ belongs to the interval $[(b-a)f^-(x,a,b),(b-a)f^+(x,a,b)].$

Hence for $a<b$ we have $(b-a)f^-(x,a,b)\le \int_a^bf(x)dx\le (b-a)f^+(x,a,b).$

Hence for $a<b$ we have  $$(\bullet) \quad f^-(x,a,b)\le \frac {\int_a^bf(x)dx}{b-a}\le 
 f^+(x,a,b).$$

Now as $b\to a$ from above $a,$ we have $f^-(x,a,b)\to f(a)$ and $f^+(x,a,b)\to f(a)$

...$(\bullet)$ because $f$ is continuous.

So as $b\to a$ from above $a,$ we have $\frac{\int_a^bf(x)dx}{b-a}\to f(a).$

An almost identical argument shows  that if $b\to a$ from below $a$ then $\frac{\int_b^af(x)dx}{a-b}\to f(a).$